# Change empty Fields using vba Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have successfully imported excel sheet to access table called tblData using vba  but the excel sheet has some empty cells, I need to change those fields in column F1 to the charecter "H". I'm good at excel vba but new to Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate an update query to perform this. You can create this using the `create> query design` in the top ribbon.

When you create a query add the table and click the update button.

Alternatively, right click and select "SQL view" and insert the following:

```
UPDATE tbldata SET tbldata.F1 = "H";
```

> EDIT: the following is to update only the empty fields in column `F1`, as mentioned by @DarrenBartrup-Cook.

```
UPDATE tbldata SET tbldata.F1 = "H" WHERE tbldata.F1 Is Null;
```

This doesn't use VBA, its a query and uses SQL. You could add some additional VBA code to your import procedure but you would have to show us the existing code.

Comment: You need to add `WHERE tbldata.F1 Is Null` (or tbldata.F1 = "" if they're empty strings rather than Nulls) to the end of that - or it will change all records to 'H' and not just the empty cells.